# Angular Material Autocomplete valueChanges is called on blur and not on change

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm playing with Angular and Angular Material autocomplete, doing a quick form to send some specific data to a backend server.
I subscribed my component to the valueChanges event, but for some reason i can't understand, the value is emitted only on input blur, so i can't call the filter function.

I've created a stackblitz so you can check the code
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9qvr9p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Running the app generates error: 
*Import error, can't find file:
/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css*